# Wicket AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior do recursive update the page

Tags: javascript, ajax, wicket

I have some ajax Behaviour that should pick some data using JS, and turn it back to Java. Sometimes it works but quite ofen it is just add url parameter and do page refresing/

```
public abstract class LoggedVKIdBehaviour extends AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggedVKIdBehaviour.class);
        @Override
        protected void respond(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            String loggedVkId = RequestCycle.get().getRequest().getRequestParameters().getParameterValue("logged_vkid").toString();
            logger.info("ajax has comming with logged VK ID " + loggedVkId);
            recived(target, loggedVkId);
        }

        protected abstract void recived(AjaxRequestTarget target, String loggedVkId);

        @Override
        public void renderHead(final Component component, IHeaderResponse response) {
            super.renderHead(component, response);

            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("callbackFunction", getCallbackFunction(CallbackParameter.explicit("logged_vkid")));
//
            PackageTextTemplate ptt = new PackageTextTemplate(LoggedVKIdBehaviour.class, "vkid_callback.js");
            OnDomReadyHeaderItem onDomReadyHeaderItem = OnDomReadyHeaderItem.forScript(ptt.asString(map));
            response.render(onDomReadyHeaderItem);
        }
}
```

js template

```
var calback = ${callbackFunction};

var logged_vk_id = 11;

function authInfo(response) {
    if (response.session) {
        logged_vk_id = response.session.mid;
        calback(response.session.mid);
        console.log("recived callback from VK " + logged_vk_id);
    }
}
$(document).ready(function () {
        VK.Auth.getLoginStatus(authInfo);
});
```

it is do recursive redirection like http://localhost:8080/mytool/product/1?logged_vkid=332797331&logged_vkid=332797331&logged_vkid=332797331&logged_vkid=332797331&logged_vkid=332773...

As i understand Ajaj technology - iti asynchronus requests, that shouldn't  touch main url at all. So what is the reason for page refreshing?

this is generated Callback function

```
function (logged_vkid) {
var attrs =     {"u":"../wicket/bookmarkable/com.tac.kulik.pages.product.ProductPage?12-1.IBehaviorListener.0-&productID=1"};
var params = [{"name":"logged_vkid","value":logged_vkid}];
attrs.ep = params.concat(attrs.ep || []);
Wicket.Ajax.ajax(attrs);
}
```

I use wicket 7.2

Comment: What is the generated replacement of `${callbackFunction}` ?

Comment: Looks good to me. No idea what goes wrong there.

Comment: thereis few news. it is comming from parent panel. In the implementation of recived(...) method i have been adding parent panel to the target. After removing this line page not do circle refreshing. But Any way it it not solving the problem. On this page i also have stateless form which has label with AjaxSelfUpdatingBehavior with duration 5 seconds. In this case i also have whole page refreshed instead of just one label

Comment: If you can reproduce this in a small demo application I'd be happy to take a look!

Comment: will try. But it's also possible to share whole project. I will be happy to give me any feedback. About source code. In case i do everything on my imagination. I am good in Android, but as for wicket-spring-ajax not so much. could show you on some call place, and steps to reproduce. By the way, preparing demo project))

Comment: Strange. But i've just coppied whole project, removed all DB stuff, authorization, all pages, and panels, leave just related suff. issue not reproduced.(((

Comment: org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: A problem occurred while trying to collect debug information about not serializable object


look like it is could come from aused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.tac.kulik.smm.panel.smaccounts.SMAccountsPanel$1

Answer (score 0):

I did a lot investigations for few days. And found that when i remove

```
setPageManagerProvider(new NoSerializationPageManagerProvider(this));
```

Application throw me exepton in polite logs

```
org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: A problem occurred while
trying to collect debug information about not serializable object look 
like it is could come from aused by: java.io.NotSerializableException:
 com.tac.kulik.panel.smaccounts.SMAccountsPanel$1
```

which means that page tryed to be serialized for SOME REASON but $1 it is mean Anonimous class. I had few class created anonimously to ges some ajax links coming from ListView to be managed on parent panel. So After removing this Anonimous class logic, everything start and run well.
So i am happy, but still don't understand which reason page did serialization after ajax, and what the reason was to refresh whole page.